# How do I find the shortest path from each node to any other specific node using R programming language in undirected graph?

Tags: r, networking, igraph, undirected-graph

Given a list of undirected and unweighted edges in an R dataframe(called edges_df, in which each row of the data frame contains id, start_x, end_x, start_y, end_y); how do I find the shortest path from each node to any specific node, say node 3(node with id=3) which is found in another data frame(called nodes_df) of nodes which has id, x_value, and y_value as it's columns, when travelling across the network edges. To make it easier, I attach below R code for creating the dataframes and screenshot of the dataframes.

```
edges_df <- data.frame(
id=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10), 
start_x=c(46646.8,46646.8,46680.2,46680.2,46713.5,46713.5,46713.5,46662.2,46662.2,46662.2), end_x=c(46646.8,46680.2,46780.5,45723.5,46813.5,46813.5,46962.2,47662.2,46662.2,44879.4), 
start_y= c(7392.8, 7392.8,7459.4,7659.4,7659.4,7852.3, 7182.7, 7143.9, 7243.9, 7899.5), 
end_y= c(7412.8, 7536.2,7346.2,7642.5, 7642.5, 7271.3,7653.7,7392.8,7921.4,7392.8)
                       )

nodes_df <- data.frame(
id=c(1,2,3,4,5), 
x_value= c(46728.9,46970.9,45236.9, 47852.9, 50123.9), 
y_value= c(7463.89,7563.89,7417.89,7417.89,7407.89)
                     )
```

edges_df

[image]

nodes_df

[image]

Comment: It's not clear to me how your nodes are connection to your edges. The x and y values don't match up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For example:

```
library(igraph)
g <- make_ring(6)
specific <- 3
distances(g, to=specific)
##      [,1]
## [1,]    2
## [2,]    1
## [3,]    0
## [4,]    1
## [5,]    2
## [6,]    3
```

This gives a matrix with all the distances from any node to a chosen node.

`?distances` shows the relevant documentation.